# Swift CAKeyframe Animation not displaying images

Tags: objective-c, animation, swift, uiimageview, cakeyframeanimation

I have set up a very simple Single View Application (in Swift) using iOS 8.1. I have added one UIImageView to the main view controller view. I am trying to use CAKeyframeAnimation to animate a sequence of images. I was originally using the UIImageView animationImages property which worked fine but I need to be able to know precisely when the animation finishes, hence the move to CAKeyframeAnimation.

My code is as follows:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
var animation : CAKeyframeAnimation!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let animationImages:[AnyObject] = [UIImage(named: "image-1")!, UIImage(named: "image-2")!, UIImage(named: "image-3")!, UIImage(named: "image-4")!]

    animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "contents")
    animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationDiscrete
    animation.duration = 25
    animation.values = animationImages
    animation.repeatCount = 25
    animation.removedOnCompletion = false
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    self.imageView.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "contents")

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

The problem is that the animation does not display any images and I just receive a blank screen. Is there something I am missing in the above code? How can I get the animation to display?

Comment: This is not exactly an answer, but do note that it makes no sense to do an animation in `viewDidLoad`. All that has happened at that time is that view has loaded into the view controller. The view is not yet in the interface. There is nothing to see at the time of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thanks Matt for the correction. In my original code base I do have it being called from viewDidAppear but in putting together the simple test project I unfortunately didn't think about the correct place to put it.

Comment: No problem - just making sure you were aware of the difference. You were!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This line is never going to work:

```
animation.values = animationImages
```

Change it to:

```
animation.values = animationImages.map {$0.CGImage as AnyObject}
```

The reason is that you are trying to animate the `"contents"` key of this layer. But that is the `contents` property. But the `contents` property must be set to a CGImage, not a UIImage. Your `animationImages`, by contrast, contains UIImages, not CGImages.

Thus you need to transform your array of UIImage into an array of CGImage. Moreover, you're trying to pass this array to Objective-C, where an NSArray must contain objects only; and since CGImage is not an object in Objective-C's mind, you need to cast each of them as an AnyObject. And that is what my `map` call does.

Comment: For a working example of this sort of "sprite" image animation, see this code from my book: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch04p149keyframeSprite/ch17p495keyframeSprite/ViewController.swift

Comment: Thanks Matt. Brilliant answer and thanks for the link to your book too, it will come in handy in future.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying the CGImage piece of the puzzle. I spent hours trying to solve this. +1